# Are jQuery() and $() aliases?

Tags: jquery

It was my understanding that `$()` whas a shortcut alias to `jQuery()` but then I read [this iterator](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.each#objectcallback). Are they two different objects then?

EDIT: thanks for the replies. Why is there no consistency in the documentation, which uses `$()` for the most part then switches to `jQuery()` in the Utilites section? That's what made me confused.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you were right. They're aliases. What that doc was trying to say there is that selecting something then iterating over the jQuery wrapper that results:

```
$(something).each(function() {...});
```

is a different function to the one on the bare object (whether you call it `$` or `jQuery`:

```
$.each(something, function() {...});
```

which can be applied to any sufficiently array-like sequence, not just jQuery wrapper objects.

Answer (score 11):

Try it yourself:

```
$ === jQuery
```

Answer (score 4):

In short - yes, they are.

Elaborating: since `$` is used by several JS frameworks jQuery has "no conflict" mode where it can be used via `jQuery()` var instead (the default one is `$`).

Answer (score 1):

yeah synonyms .. your doc page says `jQuery.each( object, callback )` .. but you can also do `$.each( object, callback )`